# What's the time complexity of Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, dijkstra

```
Dijkstra((V, E)):
  S = {}    //O(1)
  for each vertex v ∈ V:    //O(V)
    d[v] = ∞    //O(1)
  d[source] = 0    //O(1)
  while S != V:    //O(V)
    v = non visited vertex with the smallest d[v]    //O(V)
    for each edge (v, u):    //O(E)
      if u ∈/ S and d[v] + w(v, u) < d[u]:
        d[u] = d[v] + w(v, u)
    S = S ∪ {v}
```

Note: ∈/ means not in, i can't type it in the code.

This question maybe duplicates with some posts.

[Understanding Time complexity calculation for Dijkstra Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547816/understanding-time-complexity-calculation-for-dijkstra-algorithm)

[Complexity Of Dijkstra's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772780/complexity-of-dijkstras-algorithm)

[Complexity in Dijkstras algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328860/complexity-in-dijkstras-algorithm)

I read them and even some posts on Quora, but still cannot understand. I put some comments in the pseudo code and tried to work it out. I really confuse on why it is O(E log V)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "non visited vertex with the smallest d[v]" is actually O(1) if you use a [min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) and insertion in the min heap is O(log V).

Therefore the complexity is as you correctly mentioned for the other loops:

```
  O((V logV) + (E logV)) = O(E logV) // Assuming E > V which is reasonable
```

Comment: +like. nice answer. why "Assuming E > V which is reasonable" this is reasonable?

Comment: A graph with fewer edges than vertices will have disconnected components which can be ignored for the purposes of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

it is O((V logV) + (E logV)) = O(logV * (V + E)) for general graphs.

You wouldn't just assume that the graph is dense i.e. |E| = O(|V|^2) since most graphs in applications are actually sparse i.e. |E| = O(|V|).